# Pandas saving in text format

Tags: pandas

I am trying to save the output, which is a number ,to a text format in pandas after working on the dataset.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("sales.csv")
def HighestSales():
    df.drop(['index', "month"], axis =1, inplace = True)
    df2 = df.groupby("year").sum()
    df2 = df2.sort_values(by = 'sales', ascending = True).reset_index()
    df3 = df2.loc[11, 'year']
    df4 = pd.Series(df3)
    df5 = df4.iloc[0]
#*the output here is 1964 , which alone needs to be saved in the text file*.
    df5.to_csv("modified.txt")
HighestSales()
```

But I get 'numpy.int64' object has no attribute 'to_csv'- this error . Is there a way to save just one single value in the text file?

Comment: you can convert it to a dataframe or pd.Series before you write. Alternate, df5 is just a value. You can write it using regular write file and write. I see both solutions in the answer sections. One of it will solve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do:

```
# open a file named modified.txt   
with open('modified.txt', 'w') as f:
    # df5 is just an integer of 196
    # and write 1964 plus a line break
    f.write(df5 + '\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot save a single value to csv by using "pd.to_csv". In your case you should convert it into DataFrame again and then saving it. If you want to see only the number in .txt file, you need to add some parameters:

```
result = pd.DataFrame(df5)
result.to_csv('modified.txt', index=False, header=False)
```